# Mongoose push - find or update to array of objects

Tags: javascript, mongoose

My situation is as following:

I have a `session` collection, each session is a chatroom.

When a user sends a new message, other users should be notified, but to prevent spam, I need to build a check if a user got a notification mail in the last 10 minutes.

So my session collection has a `notification` array of objects with: `sessionId`, `userId` and `date`

Everytime someone sends a new message, I have to send the mails and push to the `notifications` column, but it should overwrite the `userId` to prevent the notifications column from growing.

This is what I've tried:

`sessionSchema
          .findByIdAndUpdate(sessionId, {
            $push: {
              notifications: {
                userId: userId,
                date: moment().utc().toDate()
              }
            }
          }, callback)`

However with push, the column keeps growing. How can I use push to overwrite the already created notifications by a certain userId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, try to add options in query to DB.

```
sessionSchema
          .findByIdAndUpdate(sessionId, {
            $push: {
              notifications: {
                userId: userId,
                date: moment().utc().toDate()
              }
            }
          }, { new: true }, callback)
```